# Ubuntu 22.04 Sound card doesn't work HDMI port shown input and output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa, pipewire

**I installed ubuntu 22.04 on a monster h5 computer that I bought today. The laptop I bought uses the Intel sound driver. When I try to watch a video, there is no sound. When I checked the control panel, I saw that the output sound is also used as Input. As a result of my research on the internet, I saw that no one has mentioned this problem, please, let's find a solution to it.
Giriş aygıtları= Input devices
ÇIkış aygıtları= Output devices

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9pfn.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDYfX.jpg